# Rust: What is the output of Some(Option<T>)?

Tags: vector, rust, option-type

In the Learning Rust by examples website, there is a following code:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait PrintInOption {
    fn print_in_option(self);
}

// Because we would otherwise have to express this as `T: Debug` or 
// use another method of indirect approach, this requires a `where` clause:
impl<T> PrintInOption for T where
    Option<T>: Debug {
    // We want `Option<T>: Debug` as our bound because that is what's
    // being printed. Doing otherwise would be using the wrong bound.
    fn print_in_option(self) {
        println!("{:?}", Some(self));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];

    vec.print_in_option();
}
```

Question:
In `println!("{:?}", Some(self));`, `self` is of type Option, what does Some(self) returns in this case? When I ran the code, it prints the vector.

Comment: `self` is not a type of `Option`  in here, `self` is a type of `T`(because trait is implemented for `T`).

Comment: @ÖmerErden: Maybe the OP is asking what would happen if `PrintInOption` is implemented for an `Option<Q>` type? Then `Some(self)` would be of type `Option<Option<Q>>`!

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```rust
println!("{:?}", Some(self));
```

`self` has type `T` (not `Option`). `Some()` is a constructor of the `Option` enum, so the expression

```rust
Some(self)
```

has the type `Option<T>`. In the `main()` function, `T = Vec<i32>`, so the type that gets printed is an `Option<Vec<i32>>`.